# What could I see from this check to performs background starts?

Tags: android

Google document suggests us to run this command to Check whether an app performs background starts.

```
adb shell device_config put activity_manager \
   default_fgs_starts_restriction_notification_enabled true
```

However, it does not say clearly what is the result. Is it some system notification? What is the content of the notification? Do I need to keep the phone unlocked or not?

Here is the link to the document.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions-check

Comment: it says to me /system/bin/sh: device_config: not found. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It makes a notification in the notification shade by "Android System" with a title that reads

> Foreground Service BG-Launch Restricted

With some info about the calling Package and the Intent that tried to start the service.